# How can I create a function for casting values: x `as` T = y?

Tags: idris

I have the interface for converting things of some type `this` to another type `target`.

```
interface ConvertibleTo (target : Type) (this : Type) where
    convert : this -> target
```

Can I somehow write a function, that takes some value of `this`, then the `target` type, and then produces a value of `target` type?

I've tried to write this

```
-- Example: 1 `as` String = "1"
as : ConvertibleTo target this => this -> (target : Type) -> target
as value _ = convert value
```

but it doesn't work. The compiler says

```
   |
27 | as value _ = convert value
   |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

When checking right hand side of as with expected type
    iType

Can't find implementation for ConvertibleTo iType this
```

And I do not understand that message, because I've already added a constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is, with `(target : Type)` you introduce a new variable internally called `iType` (as `target` is already assigned elsewhere), which `-> target` refers to. Because the constraint uses `target`, it should come after this argument. Constraints are just magic implicit arguments, so you don't have to put them first:

```
interface ConvertibleTo (target : Type) (this : Type) where
    convert : this -> target

as : this -> (target : Type) -> ConvertibleTo target this => target
as x _ = convert x

ConvertibleTo String Nat where
    convert = show

> as (S Z) String
"1"
```

(In case you didn't know, there is already a `ConvertibleTo` interface in the standard library with some useful implementations: `Cast from to`)